# Unable to login to SSRS Reports URL or ReportServer using a non-admin domain account

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2022, ssrs-2022

I have just setup SSRS 2022 on one of my servers with my admin account (domain\user.admin). My admin account has 'Administrator' login on the server where SSRS 2022 is installed. So when I first login using my admin account, I am able to login without any issues.

Now I am trying to add my non admin account (domain\user) as administrator. When I add using Site Settings and then try to login with my non admin account to the Reports URL, I get HTTP 500 error.

Can someone help me to fix this issue? I am not sure where I am going wrong

Note: I have a domain level service account (not admin on server) setup as service account for SSRS.

Edit: This is what I have tried so far:

1. This is a fresh install of SSRS 2022 (same happens with SSRS 2019 as well) and I have configured it with service account that has minimal permissions on server/DB instance level.
2. After configuring, I can login to both ReportServer & Reports URL with my domain\user.admin account as this account is part of BUILTIN\Administrators group.
3. I login to Reports URL and add my normal account (domain\user) as 'System user' in Site Settings and assign 'Content Manager' in Folder Settings. I also add my admin account (domain\user.admin) as 'System Administrator' in Site Settings. Once done, I have removed BUILTIN\Administrators from both Site Settings and Folder Settings.
4. Then I logged out and when I login with my domain\user account, I get HTTP 500 error. But I can login fine with my domain\user.admin account.
5. What is even more strange is, my teammate can login with his domain\user1.admin account (which is part of BUILTIN\administrators group) to Reports URL and can grant himself as 'System Administrator'. But his user account does not show up in 'Site Settings' or Folder Settings.

Is there any default option in SSRS 2019 or 2022 which enables 'BUILTIN\Administrators' to have full access? Also, why can't I access with an account which is not part of 'BUILTIN\Administrators' group?

Comment: Have you granted the account access in the web portal?

Comment: Yes. I have granted the access through 'Site Settings' -> 'Security' and gave my non admin account (domain\user) 'System Administrator' access. Even then I can't login with my domain\user login. I can only login with domain\user.admin login which is part of the 'Administrators' group on the server where SSRS resides

Comment: Have you checked SSRS' logs? HTTP 500 is an internal server error, so it seems more likely that permissions isn't the initial problem; it would be a 403 error if that were the case.

Comment: Also, I just noticed, you've tagged [[tag:SSRS-2012]] here, but your question says SSRS 2022; which is it?

Comment: Its SSRS 2022.. It didnt let me tag SSRS 2022 as there were not too many topics about it or something like that. Strangely, I can't see this HTTP 500 error in any of the logs in SSRS folder or in Windows event log.